# How to update button text after pressing button in python?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an app that will eventually be able to score cards. One problem I'm trying to solve is how to update the text of a button after pressing or updating it somehow. I'm newer to python/kivy. I've found a couple similar questions, dealing with functions and such, but none dealt with .kv files and separate windows. My code is below.

**main.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ScoreWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("mainkv.kv")


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

**mainkv.kv**

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    ScoreWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        Button:
            text: "Quick Score"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "score"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<ScoreWindow>:
    name: "score"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 7
        Button:
            name: "three"
            text: "Press to Update"
            on_release:
                three.text = "Updated"

        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: "Score"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: "Go Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Button`s can refer to themselves in kvlang using the `self` keyword. So just add another line that says `self.text = 'foo'` in the `on_release:` area of your `Button`s.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had tried that before but it's working now.